# VBA opening files which have a specific keyword in them

Tags: vba, excel

I have a folder which has a bunch of `.xls` files, of which only those which have the KEY Word " CITIES " are of interest to me. I need to open those files and collect some information and I am facing some issues.

```
Sub getTheExecSummary()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog


myPath = "C:\Users\Morpheus\Documents\Projects\Files"



myExtension = "*.xls"  'How to add the keyword?'

myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)


Do While Len(myFile) > 0
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    Debug.Print (myFile)
    Debug.Print (wb.Name)
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = wb.Name
    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

I did write a few `Debug.Print` statements none of which seem to work. I want to for now print only those workbooks which have the keyword ' CITIES ' in their name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want the Instr function.

```
If Instr(wb.Name, "CITIES") > 0 then .....
```

You might want to use "CITIES " or " CITIES " to exclude any unintentional uses of those letters, depending on how the filename is setup

Answer (score 0):

Use the wildcard to identify the missing letters: `*CITIES*.xls` or `*CITIES*.xls*` if you're expecting xlsx, xlsm, etc.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim colFiles As Collection
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Dim sPath As String

    Set colFiles = New Collection

    sPath = "C:\Users\Morpheus\Documents\Projects\Files\"
    'you could use:
    'sPath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Documents\Projects\Files\"

    EnumerateFiles sPath, "*CITIES*.xls", colFiles

    For Each vItem In colFiles
        Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(vItem)
        wrkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = wrkBk.Name
    Next vItem

End Sub

Sub EnumerateFiles(ByVal sDirectory As String, _
    ByVal sFileSpec As String, _
    ByRef cCollection As Collection)

    Dim sTemp As String

    sTemp = Dir$(sDirectory & sFileSpec)
    Do While Len(sTemp) > 0
        cCollection.Add sDirectory & sTemp
        sTemp = Dir$
    Loop
End Sub
```